# Load animation when I enter into the section

Tags: jquery, animation, progress-bar, lazy-loading

I am using a skill progress in my site. It is a circular progress bar. It has a small animation when it loads, the effect is like fill up the border. but the animation runs immediately when the page load. I want to make a way if I scroll to that section only then the animation will run.

I am using the [circliful](https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful) plugin for the progress bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize animation if the element is in viewport. Check `isElementInViewport` function on window scroll.

**Sample js**

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {

    //special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );

}

var isAnimated = false;
window.onscroll = function(){
    if(isElementInViewport($('#myStat')) && !isAnimated){
        $('#myStat').circliful();
        isAnimated = true;
    }
}
```

[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

Comment: It is working but it is cloning each progress bar 3 times. What is the reason? Thanks

Comment: you need to check the element is already animated or not. if only not then run `$('#myStat').circliful();`

Comment: how can i check if it is animated or now. the class of the element is .circlestat  . with your  If i scroll on that area the .circlestat  is cloning multiple times.  thanks

Comment: Great your new code working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.